Why are these Clow Cards under the Dark Card?
Aside from the Dream Card, the Silent Card, and the Sleep Card, why are these Clow Cards (in the list below) under the Dark Card?
List:

Change Card
Erase Card
Illusion Card
Time Card

I can definitely see and understand how the Dream Card, the Silent Card, and the Sleep Card are related to the Dark Card, but do the rest have some connection with the Dark Card compared to the Dream, the Silent, and the Sleep Card?
Are there any significant reasons?
